# I want to make a cronjob such that it runs a python script every second

Tags: python, cron

I tried making a cronjob to run my script every second, i used */60 * * * * this a parameter to run every second but it didn't worked, pls suggest me how should i run my script every second ?

Comment: That would be every minute, not every second.

Comment: how can i schedule it for every second ?? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no. Your argument - `*/60 * * * *` - means "run every 60 minutes". And you can't specify a shorter interval than 1 minute, not in standard Unix cron anyway.

Comment: ohh, thanx for correcting me, i was confused with it and thought as if it will work every second..now it made a clear picture to me.

Answer (score 0):

As written above cron can't do this. But you may use the `schedule` 3rd party package to achieve this.

https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: Thanks, need to look into this package